# excel - vba - userform - frame - set scrollbar position

Tags: excel, scrollbar, excel-2010, userform, vba

How do I set the scrollbar position of a frame(inside an userform)?

The case:

I have a frame in an userform that has dynamic content. So if the content is too big to fit the frame, it (dynamically) creates a scrollbar in that frame. The scrollbar also has dynamic values, following the frame content size.

The code that updates the scrollbar is as follows:

```
With userform1.frame1
    'dynamic size
    .ScrollHeight = param1 * param2
    .ScrollWidth = .InsideWidth * 30
End with
```

So I'd like to have something to send the scrollbar to the bottom position! How do I do that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After setting the ScrollHeight and ScrollWidth and still inside the `With` block try:

`.Scroll ActionX:=fmScrollActionNoChange, ActionY:=fmScrollActionEnd`

More details can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264840%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't know exactly why but using it like that didn't work. It didn't recognize the "ActionX". So I used it without the explicity: just `.Scroll fmScrollActionNoChange, fmScrollActionEnd `I'll try harder on the docs next time! Thanks a lot!